# Inherit metadata from folder to all documents inside folder

Tags: workflow, content-type, metadata

I am having a document library with different folders. Each folder contains 100s of documents. I am creating a new column with name Status. When I change the status of the folder to "Locked" then Status column value for all the documents under this folder should be marked as "Locked" automatically. Is there any way that I can accomplish this thing?
OOB there is no way to accomplish. Is it possible through workflow or content type?

Comment: Can you clarify 'changing the status of the folder to locked'

Comment: Status is a column that i have created for library. I will edit the properties of folder and update the Status column value to Locked

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that we can inherit metadata value from folder.But I would suggest to use document sets.

A Document Set is a group of related documents that you can manage as a single entity. You can create a Document Set in a single step, and then define its characteristics and metadata.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to inherit the metadata, I hired a consultant to develop this functionality for us, so  I can confirm its possible.  Unfortunately I cannot provide a step by step guide for your use case as our needs were different.

I believe the consultant used the SharePoint Online Management Shell which is far beyond my expertise, so unfortunately I can't do more than tempt you.